Wordpress: WORKING custom post list page with pagination throws a 404 TITLE in header
Let me start off by saying that it's NOT a 404 error issue.
I have a custom PHP post list page (basically an archive page) that pulls contents correctly, with working numbered pagination, but when I go to page 2, it shows everything correctly again but the title says '404: Page Not Found'. Debugging shows that is_404() is returning true from \wp-includes\query.php
It's weird because I fixed the rewrite rule to make it work and not throw a 404 error, but I can't fix the title of the page.
$paged = (get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
           'taxonomy' => 'category',
           'field'    => 'term_id',
           'terms'    => $catID,
           ),
        ),
        'orderby' => array('title'=>'ASC'),
     );
$post_raw = new WP_Query($args);


//building page with queried data


$total_pages = $post_raw->max_num_pages;
if($total_pages>1){
     $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

     $page = paginate_links(array(
          'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
          'format' => 'page/%#%/',
          'current' => $current_page,
          'total' => $total_pages,
          'prev_text'    => __('« '),
          'next_text'    => __(' »'),
          'type' => 'list',
          'add_args'  => array(),
      ));
               
      echo $page;
}


Provide how you call your title and what logic you use there. Just a peace of code of query args wont help much ...

I just use the $post_raw to output, so I thought it wasn't important... It's bunch of $post_raw->posts into ->ID's and stuff like that. It sounds like I'm missing some important steps, aren't I?

You get 404 bcs there is no such post as page-2 for example. Its pagination not real post. $post_raw you should use to loop your query results and thats all. You can check if you are on pagination page and call if($paged): echo 'You are on page -'.$paged; endif;
